# Why is GridView in GridLayout is getting extended below the height of the device(GridLayout)?

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin

I am using a GridView in GridLayout.
But it is getting extended below the device's height.
Any particular reason for it??
I have searched everywhere for similar issue but haven't found anything yet.

[image: ScreenShot]

This is the code for the axml... I am using Xamarin.

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
android:gravity="center"
android:rowCount="6"
android:columnCount="2">

<GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "android:layout_below" like this:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rowCount="6"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:layout_below="@id/headerRelativeLayout">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:numColumns="auto_fit"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="0" />

 </GridLayout>
```